# st. skip 'path' part of URI if it's already provided in request

Tags: javascript, node.js

my **st** instance configured with

```
var mount = st({ 
  path: './app/',
  url: '/', // defaults to path option
  index: 'index.html',
  cache: {
    fd: none,
    content: none
  }
});
```

so when I send request to `res/img/1.jpg` it goes to `./app/res/img/1.jpg` That's pretty much clear. But if  have some requests to `app/res/img/1.jpg` then it redirect this requests to `./app/app/res/img/1.jpg` and of course find nothing, because I have different file structure.

Is it possible to configure st or maybe add some custom code to skip path adding if it's already exist in URI? Or maybe it possible some way to add specific path which handles different, like some exclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it possible to do that with st directly, but you simply could add code to rewrite url if it met for some cases.

ad code like

```
var exceptions = { 
 'wrong_path':'right_path'
}

function rewriteUrl(req){
  if(exceptions[req.url]){
   req.url = exceptions[req.url];
  }
}
```

and then call that function before st method calling

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  rewriteUrl(req);
  mount(req, res);
}).listen(1234);
```